# ui date picker close if click on next

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the jquery ui datepicker plugIn (http://www.kindli.ch). Unfortunately if i click to the next or prev-icon, the hole calendar change and close immediately. jQuery is updated, ui datepicker also the newest version.

My code:

```
if($('input#datepicker_arr').length) {
                      $('#datepicker_arr').datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                        monthNames: ['Januar','Februar','März','April','Mai','Juni','Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','Dezember'],
                        dayNames: ['Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag','Samstag'],
                        dayNamesMin: ['So', 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
                        numberOfMonths: 3,

                      });
                    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Best regards
thomas

Answer (score 1):

The issue was due to your `click` event handler on `document`,

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
     var target = e.target;
     if (!$(target).is('.hasDatepicker')) $(".hasDatepicker").datepicker("hide");
 });
```

So, Here you have checked `$(target).is('.hasDatepicker')` and `hasDatepicker` class is only present on the `input` not the datepicker panel.

See the image for detail : [image]

So, To the achieve the similar functionality you could use something like following instead ,

```
 $(document).click(function (e) {
     var target = e.target;
     //If it is input Do nothing
     if ($(target).is('.hasDatepicker')) return true;
     //If current element has parent called ui-datepicker-div do nothing
     if (!$(this).closest('.ui-datepicker-div'))   
          $(".hasDatepicker").datepicker("hide");
 });
```

#### [See the Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9cu4n41z/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot - you've saved my first day after holiday;-)